# Mobile to mobile notification in parse

Tags: android, push-notification, parse-platform

I am new to parse development. Basically i am developing an android and its ios app for mobile where users can send requests and invites. For this purpose a common notification platform is required. I have heard about Parse. It works fine to send push-notification to all users like Broadcast.But i need to send a notification from one user to a single user using parse. Like in my app there will be a friend list and user can send any request to any of his friends or even send him an private message.

Comment: That's not how notifications work. When user A sends a request/message to her/his friend user B, this action will first reach your server back-end, from where appropriate action will have to be taken to send the actual notification to its proper destination.

Comment: ok it will perform any action on my server but after that how to trigger that specific push to that specific device from backend using parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand (as a summary) you want to send a push notification to specific device via using Parse cloud function. In order to send a specific  Push notification via Parse Cloud, you need to query Parse Installation table. Parse Installation keeps the devices that your application is installed. After finding the device ( device that you want to send push notification) you need to create Push via using the javascript API. One example from Parse tutorial is below;

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
query.equalTo('injuryReports', true);



Parse.Push.send({
  where: query, // Set our Installation query
  data: {
    alert: "Willie Hayes injured by own pop fly."
  }
}, {
  success: function() {
    // Push was successful
  },
  error: function(error) {
    // Handle error
  }
});
```

Hope this helps,Regards.